# Consumir Api Rest - PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, http, curl

Buenos días comunidad!

En una web que tengo (en PHP) deseo enviar archivos hacia otro sistema, dicho sistema me provee una api para realizar la acción deseada.

Mediante los diferentes endpoint que me provee la api pude traer datos de carpetas, tipos de documentos y entre otras cosas particulares de ese sistema. Todo esto utilizando file_get_contents().

Bien, de momento solo he realizado peticiones tipo GET, ahora necesito realizar la de tipo POST, para enviar un archivo. En este caso, la api ademas de tener que darle valores al endpoint me pide un body, es una estructura json la cual ya la arme. Esta estructura body la arme como el siguiente estilo:

```
                $body = [
                "file"   => $archivo_en64,
                "fileds" => array(
                    [
                        "DocumentTypeId" => $tipo_documento,
                        "DocumentId"     => 0,
                    ],
                ),
                "properties" => array(
                    [
                        "Id"             => "25",
                        "DisplayName"    => "IDTIPODOC",
                        "DefaultValue"   => array(
                            25
                        )
                    ],
                    [
                        "DisplayName"    => "NAME",
                        "DefaultValue"   => array(
                            "Gus desde Demo"
                        )
                    ],
                    [
                        "DisplayName"    => "FROMATO",
                        "DefaultValue"   => array(
                            ".TXT"
                        )
                    ]
                ),
                "policies" => null 
            ];
```

Esta estructura deberia hacerle un json_encode?

Ahora el metodo que encontre para realizar el POST a la api es mediante curl. De momento arme esto:

```
$ch = curl_init($crear_archivo);

            //setup request to send json via POST

            //attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_enconded);

            //set the content type to application/json
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

            //return response instead of outputting
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            //execute the POST request
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            echo $result;
            //close cURL resource
            curl_close($ch);
```

Pero no me funciona.
Agradeceria si me podrian ayudar con esto.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, revisa [ask]. Esta pregunta está basada en opiniones y está sujeta a ser cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones, por lo que puede terminar cerrada, por favor lee [ask] y haz el [tour]. Como consejo rapido, una firebase/php-jwt para las sesiones por token, crea los endpoints de subir, eliminar y editar y por cada archivo subido puedes crearles un id en la db con metainformación del archivo y trata de proteger la ruta, la subida de archivo puede ser la tipica de un formulario de php con sus respectivas limitaciones de seguridad.

Comment: Según mi **opinión** cURL sin ninguna duda, pero puede que otros usuarios te digan que mejor otra cosa, porque tu pregunta está basada en opiniones y podría terminar cerrada. Dicho eso, ¿cuál es el problema?, una vez has elegido la herramienta con que vas a trabajar.

Comment: Buenas tardes, actualice la pregunta, gracias!